# Why can I not call a function from a variable's definition?

Tags: c++, function

I have included the code I wrote below. I have created a function that calculates the volume of a cone based on the user's input. This is working as intended.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string.h>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

// ConeVolume prototype
float ConeVolume(float radius, float height);


int main()
{
    // Establish variables 
    float radius1;
    float height2;
    float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);

    // User input to define the varibales
    cout << "Radius: ";
    cin >> radius1;
    cout << "Height: ";
    cin >> height2;

    // Return variable using the ConeVolume function
    cout << endl << "Cone Volume: " << volumeCone;

    return 0;
}

// Function that calculates the volume of a Cone
float ConeVolume(float radius, float height)
{
    float pi = 3.14;
    float volume = (pi/3)*(radius * radius) * (height);
    
    return volume;
}
```

My question... if I were to call the function by outputting the variable "float ConeVolume" as below, why does the program return '0'? Can I not set the value of a variable equal to a function?

```
    // Return variable using the volumeCone float variable
    cout << endl << "Cone Volume: " << volumeCone;
```

Comment: `ConeVolume` is not a variable, and this is not calling any function. And why do you believe the program's explicit return value of 0, the one in its `return` statement from `main`, would be automatically changed, here? Your question is unclear.

Comment: When you reach `ConeVolume(radius1, height2);` the function is executed once using the variables `radius1` and `height2`, which do not have a value yet. The function tries the use uninitialized variables, which is Undefined Behavior. You need to assign a value to your variables before calling the function. The function call `ConeVolume(radius1, height2);` does not define any kind of relationship between `volumeCone`, `ConeVolume` or the other variables. When you change the variables `radius1` or `height2` you need to recalculate `volumeCone` explicitly again.

Comment: `float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);` does not define an equation or any relationship between the three variables. What do you think the values of `radius1` and `height2` at the point of that declaration?

Comment: Your program is doing these steps: calculate volume, get values, print volume.  You probably want to do these steps: get values, calculate volume, print volume.

Comment: OT: `#include <string.h>` can be removed.

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a huge favor once you [enable your compiler's warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/984Ko38qz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've simply made a silly mistake. You've called the 'ConeVolume' function before taking user input. So, only garbage values are being passed to the function.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string.h>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

// ConeVolume prototype
float ConeVolume(float radius, float height);


int main()
{
    // Establish variables 
    float radius1;
    float height2;

    //wrong code here
    // you've called the function before taking input of radius1 and height2
    //float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);

    // User input to define the varibales
    cout << "Radius: ";
    cin >> radius1;
    cout << "Height: ";
    cin >> height2;

    // Correct code:
    // Call the function after taking input
    float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);

    // Return variable using the ConeVolume function
    cout << endl << "Cone Volume: " << volumeCone;

    return 0;
}

// Function that calculates the volume of a Cone
float ConeVolume(float radius, float height)
{
    float pi = 3.14;
    float volume = (pi/3)*(radius * radius) * (height);
    
    return volume;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

The program return 0 because the value `volumeCone` is not being updated after you changed the values of `radius1` and `height2`.

You have to call the function `coneVolume()` again, or better yet just call it after you define `radius1` and `height2`.

```
int main()
{
    // Establish variables 
    float radius1;
    float height2;

    // User input to define the varibales
    cout << "Radius: ";
    cin >> radius1;
    cout << "Height: ";
    cin >> height2;

    float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);

    // Return variable using the ConeVolume function
    cout << endl << "Cone Volume: " << volumeCone;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the line

```
volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);
```

after the line

```
cin >> height2;
```

And change line

```
float volumeCone = ConeVolume(radius1, height2);
```

to

```
float volumeCone;
```